# Docker env variables in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I am using docker and ingestion protocol ILP to send data to questdb. I tried to export using this page env variables: https://questdb.io/docs/reference/configuration/#influxdb-line-protocol-tcp

The export commands to not work on docker - what are the docker env variables that I should be using?

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? Also, how is this related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass env vars to QuestDB in docker using the `-e` flag:

```sh
docker run -e <env_var> questdb/questdb
```

Bear in mind the formatting of env vars to be picked up by QuestDB needs to have the following:

- `QDB_` prefix
- uppercase characters
- all `.` period characters replaced with `_` underscore

The server configuration `http.bind.to` parameter has to be in the format `QDB_HTTP_BIND_TO`. For example, to run QuestDB with the HTTP / REST API exposed on port `4000`;

```sh
docker run -p 4000:4000 -e QBD_HTTP_BIND_TO=0.0.0.0:4000 questdb/questdb
```